When the running the TG mini app, I have scrolling issue
I'm currently building Telegram mini app and it is running well.
But I have some issue as below:
There is no problem when running it on the web, but there is a scrolling problem when running it in an app.
you can check the following capture.
When running it on the Iphone
https://github.com/user-attachments/assets/6f7196c5-5947-40bf-92a1-fbbfeec5a39c
When running it on the android
https://github.com/user-attachments/assets/b11bf5d9-1bf5-4654-beca-d71acc827317

Great, and how may we help you? You've found some IOS glitch. You can report it to Apple or Telegram dev team. Good luck checking again in few months!

This is probably a bug with the Telegram web view in IOS. You should report this at https://bugs.telegram.org/. This is not suitable for this site

Did you resolve the issue in any way?
